# When the springboot program starts, the filter filters the same path multiple times. What is the reason for this?

Tags: spring-boot

This is the code that my filter executes：

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    LOG.info("过滤器过滤了: " + httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

The result of startup is like this：
[结果](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpSlr.png)